# OpenCV (python) EVENT_MOUSEMOVE lags while using Trackpad on Mac

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

I'm trying to make a primitive painting app using OpenCV on Mac; however, the mouse and trackpad behave differently when they shouldn't. **EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN** sets a variable to True then **EVENT_MOUSEMOVE** draws dots along the path of the cursor. Using a mouse, everything works as expected. Using a trackpad, it seems the mouse callback gets hung-up on the EVENT_MOUSEMOVE condition. Any maverick coders have any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

drawing = False

# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global drawing

    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
    elif event == cv.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            cv.circle(img,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)
    elif event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False

img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv.namedWindow('image')
cv.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle, img)

while(1):
    cv.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Trackpad:

[Trackpad screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnAan.png)

Mouse:

[Mouse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aMRf.png)

I tried using the same code with two hardware devices (mouse, trackpad) and the mouse was the only one that worked as expected.

Comment: looks like the events are coming at a higher frequency... you'll need to deal with an actual GUI toolkit now, or figure out how to decimate those events at some point in the processing. -- tell me if this is correct: it's not _lagging_ as such. the screen simply doesn't update until you stop drawing, but when you stop, the whole stroke is there, as you drew it. right? that's caused by the pointer events somehow starving the window update. this happens on Windows at least.

Comment: Interesting! I'll dig into your higher-frequency idea and get back to you. Thank you

The screen does not really update when I stop drawing. It's as if the vast majority of points along the path never happened. So, if I log the mouse coordinates, the logging will also lag. So, for example: mouse button down then move around will only log a couple x-y points, but if I stop moving for a few seconds then slooooowly start moving again, it will log those new points from the super slow drag correctly.

Comment: Ok. I reworked the code using a different library to handle mouse movements. I then put those mouse points into a Queue, then I get those points and plot them. The line density of the mouse was less then that of the trackpad... all that to say I think you're right about the polling frequency being inconsistent. Thanks for the direction!